# how to host the mui-toolpad app production version on iisnode

Tags: toolpad

I have produced an app in mui-toolpad, and I am trying to deploy it alongside another app under iis using iisnode. There seems to be no documentation about how to do this.

So my question is:
Do you have any suggestions on how to host the production version of the  mui-toolpad app on iisnode? I am using IIS on Windows 2022 server, with iisnode already installed. I am running some react pages already through node.js and iisnode directly, in parallel with the legacy c#/MVC app, and it works well. But with mui-toolpad there seem to be a few paradigms that escape me

Grateful for any pointers

All the best